# Redirecting "tail -f" output to COPY command

Tags: bash, postgresql

I'm trying to redirect the output of the tail -f -n 1  to the Postgres COPY command, the requirement is to execute the COPY command for every output of the tail command.

Came out with the following:

```
    tail -f -n 1 <source_file> | xargs -n 1 psql -c 'copy <table_name> from stdin'
```

but this is not working as the output of the tail command is used as a parameter for the psql command rather than as stdin.

Also the more generic:

```
    tail -f -n 1 <source_file> | psql -tc "copy <table_name> from stdin"
```

is not working as the COPY command perform a commit at the end of the stream and not for every single row.

Comment: You won't be able to do this with `COPY`.

Write a script or program that performs an `INSERT` for each line of input and pipe your `tail -f` into that.

Answer (score 0):

Realized that the issue is that COPY is not intended to accept streams and data is available only when COPY command is over (end of data from program), in this specific case program was never terminated as it was intended to work as a consumer.